# How to convert int to string in a ternary operation

Tags: c++, string, casting, type-conversion, conditional-operator

When trying to do a ternary operation using an integer and string such as:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 100; num++) {
    cout << (i % 10 == 0) ? "Divisible by 10" : num;
}
```

You end up with the following exception

> [E0042](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%2B%2B%20operand%20types%20are%20incompatible%20(%20and)):       operand types are incompatible ("const char*" and "int")

If you were to try to cast `num` to `const char*` by doing `(const char*)num` you will end up with an access violation.
If you do `(const char*)num&` instead, you get the ASCII character corresponding to the value.

For numbers greater than 10 how can you *quickly* cast that integer into a string? (Preferably in the same line)

Comment: `cout << (i % 10 == 0) ? std::string("Divisible by 10") : std::to_string(num);` or because `"Divisible by 10"` is convertible to `std::string`: `cout << (i % 10 == 0) ? "Divisible by 10" : std::to_string(num);`

Comment: Ditch the ternary operator and use an if statement.  `if (i % 10) std::cout << num; else std::cout << "Divisible by 10";`

Comment: Is there a faster way to do it, maybe without using string?

Comment: it gets converted to some sort of "string" anyway so I would consider looking for something faster only if I encounter an actual performance problem and know (through profiling) that this function is the reason

Comment: *Is there a faster way to do it, maybe without using string?*  Have you **profiled** an *optimized build* for how long it takes to do it each way?  That's the best way to ascertain performance impact.

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. If an expression can return 2 different types then how can you assign that to a variable? Or which overload should be called in `std::cout::operator<<((i % 10 == 0) ? "Divisible by 10" : num)`?

Comment: btw the operator is called "conditional operator". "ternary operator" is a general term like "unary" or "binary operator". It just happens that the conditional operator is the only ternary operator in C++ (but in principle there could be others)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you're not looking for a **cast** here; you're looking for a **conversion**. A cast is something that you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @Keegan: You would be *amazed* at how hard it is to beat `std::string` in terms of performance. `std::string( "Divisible by 10" )`, for example, is unlikely to use any dynamic memory allocation in the firsr place.

Comment: @KeeganMcGonigle Instead of `i % 10 == 0`, did you want `num % 10 == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on the conditional operator, you could write this:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 100; num++) {
    (num%10==0) ? std::cout << "Divisible by 10" : std::cout << num;
}
```

If you want to stay with yours, you need to convert the values to some compatible types. There is no way around that. The conditional operator is not an equivalent replacement for an `if-else` statement and often the latter is much clearer:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 100; num++) {
    if (num%10==0) { std::cout << "Divisible by 10"; }
    else { std::cout << num; }
}
```

---

> For numbers greater than 10 how can you quickly cast that integer into a string? (Preferably in the same line)

`std::to_string` can convert numbers to strings.

---

PS: To illustrate an example where an `if-else` cannot be used and the conditional operator is actually useful, consider the initialization of a reference. You cannot write:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int& ref;    // nope, error
if (condition) ref = x;   
else ref = y;
```

but you can write:

```
int& ref = (condition) ? x : y;
```

There are other cases where the conditional operator is useful. It's purpose is not just to save a line of code compared to an `if-else`.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do that int the same line, try:

```cpp
for (int num = 0; num < 100; num++) {
    cout << (num % 10 == 0 ? "Divisible by 10" : to_string(num)) << endl;
}
```